# Is your local collection of docker images a registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have been reading about docker registries and know that I can spin up a registry image. My question is:

By default when running docker I have images stored locally. Does this not mean that I have a docker registry? Or is that considered something else like a local cache or something?

What does running the docker registry image give in addition to this? Is it just a web client for my local images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you have stored locally are not a registry. A registry is potentially usable from several machines. You would push an image to the registry to make it available for other hosts that have access to the registry. They can then pull the image from the registry to local storage.